# Bars not plotted in D3 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have built a stacked chart using d3. But first data is plotted, but the second data is not getting plotted. The data is being fetched from an API, and the numbers possibly will have a huge difference. In the first data, E is not plotted in graph and the bar exceeds height of Y-axis. And, second one is not drawn at all. How to fix this. I checked several examples and the code I followed is same I think. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Also, here I have given a fixed bar size. The bar is not drawn in the center, but towards left. I needed each bar to be plotted in the middle.

Code,

```
const data = [
{'category': 'Type 1', A: 0, B: 1402574577, C: 0, D: 19197208547, E: 1792937}, {category: 'Type 2', A: 14600000, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 2369530}]
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
const cost = [
    [0, 1402574577, 0 , 19197208547, 1792937],
    [14600000, 0, 0, 0, 2369530]
]

const width = 500;
const height = 300;
const margin = {left: 100, top: 60, right: 60};

let svg = d3
      .select('#stackedbars')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top * 2)
      .style('background', '#fff');
      
svg = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

const xScaleRange = data.length * 120;

const x = d3.scaleBand()
         .rangeRound([0, xScaleRange])
         .padding(0.1)
         
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
  
const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(keys)
          .range(["#F6D7A7", "#F6EABE", "#C8E3D4", "#87AAAA", "#247291"]);
x.domain(data.map(d => d.category));
y.domain([0, d3.max(cost.flat())]).nice()

const gX = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
  .filter((d, i, nodes) => i < nodes.length - 1)
  .clone()
  .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
  .attr('x1', x.step() / 2)
  .attr('x2', x.step() / 2)
  .attr('y1', -height)
  .attr('y2', 0));

const gY = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, 's').tickFormat(d => d))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
  .filter((d, i) => i > 0)
  .clone()
  .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', width));

gX.selectAll("line")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gX.selectAll("path")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("line")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("path")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("text")
  .style("fill", "#8a8a8a");
  
const dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);
const layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
    .data(dataStackLayout)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "stack")
    .style("fill",  (d) => {
      return z(d.key)
    });

layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", d => {
    return x(d.data.category)
  })
  .attr("y",  d => y(d[1]))
  .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
  .attr("width", "25")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct. The problem is with values and scales. See an example in the snippet:

```js
const data = [
{'category': 'Type 1', A: 10, B: 20, C: 30, D: 40, E: 50}, {category: 'Type 2', A: 50, B: 40, C: 30, D: 20, E: 10}]
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
const colors = {
 'A': 'red',
 'B': 'green',
 'C': 'blue',
 'D': 'yellow',
 'E': 'orange'
};

const width = 500;
const height = 300;
const margin = {left: 100, top: 60, right: 60};

let svg = d3
      .select('#stackedbars')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top * 2)
      .style('background', '#fff');
      
svg = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

const xScaleRange = data.length * 120;

const x = d3.scaleBand()
         .rangeRound([0, xScaleRange])
         .padding(0.1)
         
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, 200])
          .range([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(d => d.category));

const gX = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
  .filter((d, i, nodes) => i < nodes.length - 1)
  .clone()
  .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
  .attr('x1', x.step() / 2)
  .attr('x2', x.step() / 2)
  .attr('y1', -height)
  .attr('y2', 0));

const gY = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, 's').tickFormat(d => d))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
  .filter((d, i) => i > 0)
  .clone()
  .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', width));

gX.selectAll("line")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gX.selectAll("path")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("line")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("path")
  .style("stroke", "#eeeeee");

gY.selectAll("text")
  .style("fill", "#8a8a8a");
  
const dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);
const layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
    .data(dataStackLayout)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "stack")
    .style("fill",  (d) => {
      return colors[d.key]
    });

layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", d => {
    return x(d.data.category) + 35
  })
  .attr("y",  d => y(d[1]))
  .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
  .attr("width", 30)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="stackedbars" />
```